# Change 'favorite' tags background color please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, watched-tags

They are really hard to differentiate because the color is almost white: `#EEFAFF` vs `#FFFFFF`. It might be my 26 year old eyes or it might be my screen, but I really have a hard time telling them apart.

Please consider. Thanks :).

Comment: I guess that's a no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carlo, I have darkened the interesting question bgcolor a bit. It will be in the next deployment. thanks. Here's a preview:

[image]